# android WebView and font size

Tags: android, webview

I have a need for "rich text formatting" so I'm using a webview as a custom single line text edit.

I'd like to set the font size to be 90% of the height of the webview, in all resolutions and densities.

Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 0):

WebView just displays web pages (more accurately, HTML), so all your text formatting has to be done in HTML/CSS.

You may want to try a [TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) and have a look at using [Html.fromHtml()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml%28java.lang.String%29) to style your text.  Then you can use TextView's sizing capabilities.

Comment: does fromHtml() support css? from my test it does not seem to be

Comment: I don't believe so, but it's not documented very well.